# Weak convergence (exercise)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\,\,\,f_h : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the functions defined by $f_h(x) = h$ if $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{h}$ and $0$ otherwise. Prove that there do not exist a subsequence $(f_{h_{k}})_k$ and $f \in L^1((0,1))$ such that $f_{h_{k}} \rightharpoonup f $ in $L^1((0,1))$.

I have no idea how to resolve this exercise, can anyone help me?

Comment: The sequence goes to zero pointwise thus if any subsequence converged in $L^1$, it would have to converge to zero in $L^1$. But $\| f_h\|_1 =1$ for all $h >1$ so this is impossible.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. In this way you proved that the sequence doesn't admit a subsequence converging in the norm of $L^1$, right? But I have to prove that the sequence doesn't admit a subsequence converging weakly. My attempt is to use the definition of weak convergence. Suppose that $(f_{h_{k}})_k$ exists and converges (weakly) to $f \in L^1$, so

\[
\langle  f_{h_{k}} , g \rangle \rightarrow \langle f, g \rangle \qquad \forall g \in (L^1)^{'} = L^\infity,
\]

i.e.

\[
\int_0^h h g(x) \,dx \rightarrow \int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx.
\]
But now I don't know how to go further..

Comment: I see; I missed the work "Weak" but the same reasoning applies. Since $f_h\to 0$ pointwise, if any subsequence converged weakly, then it would have to converge weakly to $0$. However, we see $$\langle f_h, 1 \rangle = \int^{1/h}_0 h \,\, dx = 1$$for all $h > 1$ so no subsequence can to to $0$ weakly because pairing with the constant function $1$, the inner product fails to go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there exists a subsequence $\left(f_{h_k}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ and a function $f$ such that $f_{h_k}\to f$ weakly in $\mathbb L^1$. For positive integers $M$ and $N$, define the function 
$$
g_{M,N}:=\mathbf 1\left\{x\in [0,1]\mid f(x)\gt \frac  1M\mbox{ and }x\gt \frac 1N\right\}.
$$
Then for $k$ such that $h_k\gt N$, the function $f_{h_k} g_{M,N}$ is identically zero hence 
$$
0=\int fg_{M,N}\geqslant \frac 1M \lambda\left\{x\in [0,1]\mid f(x)\gt \frac  1M\mbox{ and }x\gt \frac 1N\right\}
$$
which shows that $f(x)\leqslant 1/M$ on $[1/N,1]$.  Since this is valid for any $M$ and $N$, we derive that $f(x)\leqslant 0$ almost everywhere. 
Applying the definition of weak convergence to the function $g$ constant equal to $1$ leads to a contradiction.